# Advanced Excel 2007 selecting mutually exclusive observations in columns

Tags: excel

I have a table like the one below

```
Place   Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
1        yes    yes     yes
2        no     yes     yes
3        yes    no      yes
4        no     no      no
5        no     no      no
6        no     no      no
7        no     no      no
```

I need to select the first yes in the the first column, once selected that place cannot be used in the second or third columns. For example the first yes in col 2 cannot be 1 because it was used in column 1 therefore I select the yes in position 2. In the third column we can't select the first or second yes because they have been used in col1 and col 2 therefore the only available first in line yes is number 3. I need this to be driven by formulas i.e. change randomly the order of yes and nos but never have the same yes selected in the same position regardless of column. 
For example we can show the yes positions down the bottom like

```
Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
1       2       3
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't catch it... could you try to be clearer?

Comment: Difficult to understand. Can you make it more specific?

Answer (score 0):

1. Under the column 1, use this formula:

   ```
   =MATCH("yes",B$2:B$8,0),
   ```

   where `B$2:B$8` is the data in the first column.
2. Under the column 2, use this formula:

   ```
   =MATCH("yes",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(ROW(C$2:C$8)-ROW(C$2)+1,$B$12:B$12,0)),C$2:C$8,"no"),0)
   ```

   where `B12` is the cell with the first formula.
   **Make sure you [press Ctrl+Shift+Enter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) to enter this formula.**
3. Drag the second formula to the right for as many columns as you want.